# Most efficient way to calculate frequency of pairs of numbers in a 2D Numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, processing-efficiency

Let's say I have the following 2D array:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
a = np.random.randint(1, 6, size=(5, 3))
```

which produces:

```
In [371]: a
Out[371]:
array([[3, 5, 3],
       [2, 4, 3],
       [4, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2]])
```

is there a more efficient (Numpy, Pandas, etc.) way to calculate a freuency of all pairs of numbers than [the following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32214841/5741205)?

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations

def pair_freq(a, sort=False, sort_axis=-1):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    if sort:
        a = np.sort(a, axis=sort_axis)
    res = Counter()
    for row in a:
        res.update(combinations(row, 2))
    return res

res = pair_freq(a)
```

to produce something like that:

```
In [38]: res
Out[38]:
Counter({(3, 5): 1,
         (3, 3): 1,
         (5, 3): 1,
         (2, 4): 1,
         (2, 3): 1,
         (4, 3): 1,
         (4, 2): 2,
         (2, 2): 2,
         (1, 2): 4,
         (1, 1): 1})
```

or:

```
In [39]: res.most_common()
Out[39]:
[((1, 2), 4),
 ((4, 2), 2),
 ((2, 2), 2),
 ((3, 5), 1),
 ((3, 3), 1),
 ((5, 3), 1),
 ((2, 4), 1),
 ((2, 3), 1),
 ((4, 3), 1),
 ((1, 1), 1)]
```

PS the resulting dataset might look differently - for example like a multi-index Pandas DataFrame or something else.

I was trying to increase the dimensionality of the `a` array and to use `np.isin()` together with the a list of a combinations of all pairs, but I still couldn't get rid of a loop.

**UPDATE:**

> **(a)** Are you interested only in the frequency of combinations of 2 numbers (and not interested in frequency of combinations of 3
>   numbers)?

yes, i'm interested in combinations of pairs (2 numbers) only

> **(b)** Do you want to consider (3,5) as distinct from (5,3) or do you want to consider them as two occurrences of the same thing?

actually both approaches are fine - I can always sort my array beforehand if I need:

```
a = np.sort(a, axis=1)
```

**UPDATE2:**

> Do you want the distinction between (a,b) and (b,a) to happen only due
>   to the source column of a and b, or even otherwise? Do understand this
>   question, please consider three rows `[[1,2,1], [3,1,2], [1,2,5]]`.
>   What do you think should be the output here? What should be the
>   distinct 2-tuples and what should be their frequencies?

```
In [40]: a = np.array([[1,2,1],[3,1,2],[1,2,5]])

In [41]: a
Out[41]:
array([[1, 2, 1],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 5]])
```

I would expect the following result:

```
In [42]: pair_freq(a).most_common()
Out[42]:
[((1, 2), 3),
 ((1, 1), 1),
 ((2, 1), 1),
 ((3, 1), 1),
 ((3, 2), 1),
 ((1, 5), 1),
 ((2, 5), 1)]
```

because it's more flexible, so I want to count (a, b) and (b, a) as the same pair of elements I could do this:

```
In [43]: pair_freq(a, sort=True).most_common()
Out[43]: [((1, 2), 4), ((1, 1), 1), ((1, 3), 1), ((2, 3), 1), ((1, 5), 1), ((2, 5), 1)]
```

Comment: **(a)** Are you interested only in the frequency of combinations of 2 numbers (and not interested in frequency of combinations of 3 numbers)? **(b)** Do you want to consider `(3,5)` as distinct from `(5,3)`, or do you want to consider them as two occurrences of the same thing?

Comment: @fountainhead, thank you for your comment! I've extended my questions with an additional information...

Comment: In your sample data, the first row has `(3,5,3)`, which generates the 2-tuples `(3,5)` and `(5,3)`. Your current solution treats these two tuples as distinct, presumably because the `3` in `(3,5)` comes from the first column, and the `3` in `(5,3)` comes from the third column. Do you want to stick with that distinction? Just double-checking despite your edit.

Comment: Related question. The row `[1,2,2]` generates the 2-tuple `(1,2)` twice (since `2` is present in two different columns), and your current solution treats these two 2-tuples as distinct. Is that distinction important?

Comment: @fountainhead, yes, I think counting `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` as distinct pairs would gives us more flexibility

Comment: @fountainhead. `The row [1,2,2] generates the 2-tuple (1,2) twice (since 2 is present in two different columns), and your current solution treats these two 2-tuples as distinct. Is that distinction important?` - yes, I'd like to count `(1,2)` twice in this case

Comment: Do you want the distinction between `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` to happen only due to the source column of `a` and `b`, or even otherwise? Do understand this question, please consider three rows `[1,2,1]`. `[3,1,2]`, and `[1,2,5]`. What do you think should be the output here? What should be the distinct 2-tuples and what should be their frequencies?

Comment: I think my last question is tantamount to asking do you want permutations instead of combinations. So, I think you may pls ignore that question.

Comment: @fountainhead, i tried to extend my answer, so that it clarifies your questions in comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your elements are not too large nonnegative integers `bincount` is fast:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np

def pairs(a):
    M = a.max() + 1
    a = a.T
    return sum(np.bincount((M * a[j] + a[j+1:]).ravel(), None, M*M)
               for j in range(len(a) - 1)).reshape(M, M)

def pairs_F_3(a):
    M = a.max() + 1
    return (np.bincount(a[1:].ravel() + M*a[:2].ravel(), None, M*M) +
            np.bincount(a[2].ravel() + M*a[0].ravel(), None, M*M))

def pairs_F(a):
    M = a.max() + 1
    a = np.ascontiguousarray(a.T) # contiguous columns (rows after .T)
                                  # appear to be typically perform better
                                  # thanks @ning chen
    return sum(np.bincount((M * a[j] + a[j+1:]).ravel(), None, M*M)
               for j in range(len(a) - 1)).reshape(M, M)

def pairs_dict(a):
    p = pairs_F(a)
    # p is a 2D table with the frequency of (y, x) at position y, x
    y, x = np.where(p)
    c = p[y, x]
    return {(yi, xi): ci for yi, xi, ci in zip(y, x, c)}

def pair_freq(a, sort=False, sort_axis=-1):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    if sort:
        a = np.sort(a, axis=sort_axis)
    res = Counter()
    for row in a:
        res.update(combinations(row, 2))
    return res


from timeit import timeit
A = [np.random.randint(0, 1000, (1000, 120)),
     np.random.randint(0, 100, (100000, 12))]
for a in A:
    print('shape:', a.shape, 'range:', a.max() + 1)
    res2 = pairs_dict(a)
    res = pair_freq(a)
    print(f'results equal: {res==res2}')
    print('bincount', timeit(lambda:pairs(a), number=10)*100, 'ms')
    print('bc(F)   ', timeit(lambda:pairs_F(a), number=10)*100, 'ms')
    print('bc->dict', timeit(lambda:pairs_dict(a), number=10)*100, 'ms')
    print('Counter ', timeit(lambda:pair_freq(a), number=4)*250,'ms')
```

Sample run:

```
shape: (1000, 120) range: 1000
results equal: True
bincount 461.14772390574217 ms
bc(F)    435.3669326752424 ms
bc->dict 932.1215840056539 ms
Counter  3473.3258984051645 ms
shape: (100000, 12) range: 100
results equal: True
bincount 89.80463854968548 ms
bc(F)    43.449611216783524 ms
bc->dict 46.470773220062256 ms
Counter  1987.6734036952257 ms
```

Comment: The solution is probably fast, but the solution provider was even faster !

Comment: Suppose that the shape of `a` is m,n. When m >> n, the code run more quickly in a with 'F' order.

Comment: @ningchen actually, changing to column major appears to be worth it most of  the time; it did for all parameters I tried!

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea, the code as follow. 
The hugest disadvantage of my code is that it run very slowly as the column increase, and it is slower than code from @Paul Panzer. I apologize to Paul Panzer.

And if you want to be more quick, just ignore the function for num_to_items. because `(1, 1)` is equal to `1*2**20 + 1`.

```
import numpy as np
from random import choice
from itertools import izip
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, csc_matrix
from scipy import sparse as sp


c_10 = np.array([[choice(range(1, 10)) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(1000)])
c_1000 = np.array([[choice(range(1, 1000)) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(1000)])

def _bit_to_items(num):
    return (num >> 20, num & 0b1111111111111111111)


def unique_bit_shit(c):
    cc = c << 20 # suppose that: 2**20 > max(c)

    dialog_mtx_1 = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                             [1, 0, 0],
                             [0, 1, 0]])

    dialog_mtx_2 = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                             [0, 0, 1],
                             [0, 0, 1]])

    dialog_mtx_1 = dialog_mtx_1.T
    dialog_mtx_2 = dialog_mtx_2.T

    pairs = cc.dot(dialog_mtx_1) + c.dot(dialog_mtx_2)
    pairs_num, count = np.unique(pairs, return_counts=True)
    return [(_bit_to_items(num), v) for num, v in izip(pairs_num, count)]



def _dot_to_items(num):
    # 2**20 is 1048576
    return (num / 1048576, num % 1048576) 


def unique_dot(c):
    dialog_mtx_3 = np.array([[2**20, 2**20, 0],
                             [1,     0,     2**20],
                             [0,     1,     1]])

    pairs = c.dot(dialog_mtx_3)

    pairs_num, count = np.unique(pairs, return_counts=True)
    return [(_dot_to_items(num), v) for num, v in izip(pairs_num, count)]
```

Comment: _"when the range of elements in a is very large"_ actually the correct condition would be "if the range is large compared to array size". For example if you increase the number of rows to `10000` in your arrays then bincount is faster. Also, does your code work for anything other than 3 columns?

Comment: As you said, my test don't cover all cases. 'My code is more quick' is not preciseness.

Comment: @Paul Panzer. The cost time of `np.dot` and `np.unique` increase as the number of columns increase. So `unique_dot` will be very slow as columns more than 100, with `csc_matrix.dot`, it will be quick but still slower than your code.